# Exponent can't be pulled from limit

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Using the limit property $$\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)^{n}] = \left(\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)]\right)^{n},$$ it seems to me that $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{x^{-1}}\right] = \left(\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]\right)^{-1}$$ but this would equal $0^{-1}$ which is undefined. I'm wondering why the exponent limit property doesn't seem to hold in this case. 
Thanks.

Comment: The LHS is also undefined, so what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit property says:  if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \left[f(x)\right]^n=\left[\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)\right]^n=L^n$.

Since your limit does not exist, you will not get anything meaningful by rewriting the expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wolfram alpha gives the result of the limit as $\infty$ so I think I'm misinterpreting something. I'm covering calc for the first time so my skills are pretty bad.

Comment: @JakeWickham $\infty$ is not a number.  For the limit to exist, the expression must converge to a particular number, which I denote as $L$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I marked your response as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This requires that both of the limits actually exist. In this case however,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{-1}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} x$$
does not exist.